# How to pass an enum to a method without passing it as an integer

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe7

I Have an enum which contains 3 different values

```
enum
{
    inputValidation_Zipcode,
    inputValidation_String,
    inputValidation_Number
} InputValidation;
```

I am trying to pass one of these three enum values to a method, and have tried the following.

```
bool methodName(enum InputValidation inputenum)

bool methodName(InputValidation inputenum)
```

and ofc

```
bool methodName(int inpoutenum)
```

(All three called as methodName(InputValidation_Number) )

I know the last one will "work" but allows ALL integers as arguments. How can I Write a method to only accept the inputValidation values?

Comment: `InputValidation` is a variable name, not a type. That is why you can't use it as a parameter type. Jarod's answer shows you how to declare `InputValidation` as a type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your enum definition is wrong, it should be:

```cpp
enum /*class*/ InputValidation
{
    inputValidation_Zipcode,
    inputValidation_String,
    inputValidation_Number
};
```

Then you might use:

```cpp
bool methodName(InputValidation inputenum);
```

Comment: This will still allow general `int` values to be passed to the method

Answer (score 1):

Give scoped enum a try by adding `class` as follows:

```cpp
enum class InputValidation
{
    inputValidation_Zipcode,
    inputValidation_String,
    inputValidation_Number
};
```

For more information:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum